# Ошибка Yii2: Cannot create symlink под Windows

Tags: php, yii2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]При установке шаблона kit-starter на yii2 возникла ошибка.
Сама ошибка на скриншоте [image: скрин ошибки]

Comment: пожалуйста, никогда больше не выкладывайте _текст_ ошибок как картинки!

Comment: почему? Я сам только зарегистрировался тут, поэтому еще не совсем со всем разобрался

Comment: в следущий раз учту

Answer (score 1):

Не создается симлинк под windows, в конфиге добавьте `'linkAssets' => false,`

```
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\AssetManager',
        'linkAssets' => false,
        ....
    ]
],
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: там начинает выпадать данная ошибка на втором скрине

Comment: новый вопрос создайте. с новой ошибкой